# jQuery sortable - does the handle have to be existing DOM element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When using sortable and you want to give it a handle option, does the selector you choose have to be an existing element on the dom at the time that sortable is called?

If so, is there anyway to use a class for elements that will be dynamically added later?

Sample code:

```
$("#sortableMembers").sortable
({
    connectWith: "#sortableMembers",
    cursor: "move",
    delay: "150",
    revert: 200,

    start: function (e, ui)
    {
        //Workaround for the height being too small... make the height of the placeholder the same size
        //as the height of the container being dragged
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    }
});
```

Then when I add a .member element I call

```
$('#sortableMembers').sortable('option', 'handle', '.member');
```

I did .draggable but it just let me drag elements around the screen it didnt sort them. The above doesnt do anything.

Comment: Please clarify how items are being *added* to your sortable? Dynamically adding them from another list or by dragging? Programmaticly?

Comment: Im adding them programmatically. I create an element and then just append it to the dom under the element i set as sortable

Answer (score 0):

> Does the selector you choose have to be an existing element on the DOM at the time that sortable is called?

Yes it does. Also note that it has to be a descendant of the element(s) you're defining as draggable.

> If so, is there anyway to use a class for elements that will be dynamically added later?

You can update the options of the draggable later on, after appending the new item with its handle, like this:

```
$('.draggable').draggable('option', 'handle', '.handle-selector');
```

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken with my last comment, jumped the gun. When I set it draggable it just lets me drag the elements around. I tried setting .sortable instead but it doesnt do anything. \

Comment: I didn't see your last comment, so I'm not sure what you mean. However if you have issues with this it would really help if you could edit your question to include a working sample of your code.

Comment: Updated there now.